# Unpivot Data in Dbeaver using query

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot, dbeaver

I have below set of data where the ship from and ship to location for a tracking ID is mentioned in two different row -

For ID 1234 CA is the ship from City and WA is the ship to City

| ID | Type | City | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | From | CA | ABC |
| 1234 | To | WA | XYZ |

I want to create a new table to have the Ship from location and Ship To City in the same row like below

| ID | From City | From State | To City | To State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | CA | ABC | WA | XYZ |

Can someone help what should be the syntax to achieve this result ?

Comment: Join the table on itself to get both rows together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do aggregation with condition:

```
SELECT ID
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'From' THEN City END)
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'From' THEN State END)
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'To' THEN City END)
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'To' THEN State END)
FROM #MyTable 
GROUP BY ID
```